# How does the reducer function know that count is a state's item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do not understand how reducer knows that count is from state without using state's name in the code. I thought it was like "`return {state.count: state.count + 1}`". How does it work?

```js
import { useReducer } from 'react';
    
    const initialState = {count: 0};
    
    const reducer = (state, action) =>{
      switch(action.type){
        case 'minus':
          return {count: state.count + 1}
        break;
        case 'plus':
          return {count: state.count - 1}
        break;
        case 'reset':
          return initialState;
        break;
      }
      return state;
    }
    
    const App = () =>{
      const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    
      return(
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'menos'})}>-</button>
          <div>{state.count}</div>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'mais'})}>+</button>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'reset'})}>reset</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want to know. If you want to view the source code for the `useReducer` hook, it's [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v18.1.0/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L87). Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been declared reducer function and actions. Your dispatch look your actions type and change the state accordingly.you dont need to give states name only need to give actions type.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).